# Integration test of Neo4j in spring boot fails to rollback the inserted object=nodes

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit4, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I use Spring Boot 1.5.1 and the SDN release of 4.2.0. I am new to spring boot and Neo4j. I wanted to test my repository as a first step. 
I used the same Neo4j related context for test as I used for development based on HttpDriver:

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("hu.bookandwalk.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyNeo4jConfig {
    @Bean
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration(){
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config=new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver").setURI("http://xxx:yyyy@localhost:7474");

        /*autoindex feature based on annotation is false in default*/
        config.autoIndexConfiguration().setAutoIndex("assert");
        return config;
    } 

    @Bean
    /*In Spring Data Neo4j 4.2 the name of the bean is important to be sessionFactory*/
    SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "hu.bookandwalk.domain");
    }

    /*In Spring Data Neo4j 4.2 the name of the bean is important to be transactionManager @link http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html*/
    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

My test always failed so I started to debug the integration test itself. My test class is the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyNeo4jConfig.class})
public class RepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    Session session;

    @Autowired
    BnWUserRepository bnwUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Autowired
    InvoiceDataRepository invoiceDataRepository;

    @Test
    public void ShouldInsertUser(){
        BnwAddress a1=new BnwAddress("Hungary", "Budapest", "1092","Erkel utca 9.");
        BnwAddress a2=new BnwAddress("Hungary", "Budapest", "1092","Ráday utca 9.");
        InvoiceData i1=new InvoiceData("Book and Walk Kft","23345",true,a1);

        BnWUser u=new BnWUser(1l,"Roland","roland.szucs@gmail.com","password",true,true,true);
        u.addAddress(a1);
        u.addAddress(a2);
        u.addInvoiceData(i1);
        bnwUserRepository.save(u);
        assertEquals(bnwUserRepository.findOne("Roland").getUserEmail(),"roland.szucs@gmail.com");

    /*@After
    public void cleaning(){
        session.purgeDatabase();
    }*/

}
```

When I started to debug the test, it turned out that my @Test annotated method runs as expected but as soon as spring/Neo4j start to rollback the transaction i get the following exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionManagerException: Transaction is not current for this thread
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.rollback(DefaultTransactionManager.java:89) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.rollback(AbstractTransaction.java:67) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.transaction.HttpTransaction.rollback(HttpTransaction.java:59) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.close(AbstractTransaction.java:141) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:311) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1016) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:883) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:125) ~[spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:227) ~[spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:319) ~[spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
```

First, I thought that my @After annotated method throws the exception so I commented it out. I still got the same error.
I set the log level of Neo4j to debug and you can see the relevant debug log items until the exception:

```
**2017-02-21 12:11:18.941 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Opened new Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@74cf8b28] for Neo4j OGM transaction**
2017-02-21 12:11:18.941 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: beginTransaction()
2017-02-21 12:11:18.941 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: Neo4jSession identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@1f9d6c7b
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, POST http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, text: {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/7/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:12:18 +0000"},"errors":[]}
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, Connection released
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: Transaction, tx id: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.transaction.HttpTransaction@79c5636f
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Beginning Transaction [org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.transaction.HttpTransaction@79c5636f] on Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@74cf8b28]
2017-02-21 12:11:18.957  INFO 5604 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@e720b71 testClass = RepositoryTests, testInstance = hu.bookandwalk.RepositoryTests@718607eb, testMethod = ShouldInsertUser@RepositoryTests, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1b26f7b2 testClass = RepositoryTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class hu.bookandwalk.config.MyNeo4jConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@42dafa95, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@59ec2012, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@55d56113], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager@27f3b6d6]; rollback [true]
2017-02-21 12:11:19.004 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@74cf8b28] for Neo4j OGM transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.004 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.004 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils  : Registering transaction synchronization for Neo4j Session
2017-02-21 12:11:19.035 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context initialised with 0 relationships
2017-02-21 12:11:19.051 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : visiting: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d
2017-02-21 12:11:19.051 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d has changed
2017-02-21 12:11:19.051 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping references declared by: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d 
2017-02-21 12:11:19.051 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping reference type: HAS_INVOICEDATA
2017-02-21 12:11:19.051 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : linking to entity hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c in one direction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : visiting: hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c has changed
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping references declared by: hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c 
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping reference type: HAS_ADDRESS
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : linking to entity hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6 in one direction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : visiting: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6 has changed
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping references declared by: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6 
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : trying to map relationship between hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c and hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context-new: (-37268876)-[-1062181581:HAS_ADDRESS]->(-930900166)
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : trying to map relationship between hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d and hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context-new: (-814245389)-[-1219553025:HAS_INVOICEDATA]->(-37268876)
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping reference type: HAS_DELIVERYINFO
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : linking to entity hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6 in one direction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : already visited: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : trying to map relationship between hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d and hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context-new: (-814245389)-[-1011104118:HAS_DELIVERYINFO]->(-930900166)
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : linking to entity hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2 in one direction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : visiting: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2 has changed
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping references declared by: hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2 
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : trying to map relationship between hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d and hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context-new: (-814245389)-[-62739928:HAS_DELIVERYINFO]->(-1401737458)
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: beginTransaction()
2017-02-21 12:11:19.066 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: Neo4jSession identity: org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate@6f63c44f
2017-02-21 12:11:19.082 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, POST http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.082 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.082 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, text: {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:12:19 +0000"},"errors":[]}
2017-02-21 12:11:19.082 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, Connection released
2017-02-21 12:11:19.082 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 1: Transaction, tx id: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.transaction.HttpTransaction@408a247c
2017-02-21 12:11:19.098 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, request url http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8
2017-02-21 12:11:19.098  INFO 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MERGE (n:`BnWUser`{userName: row.props.userName}) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-814245389,"type":"node","props":{"password":"password","newsletterSubscribed":true,"active":true,"notficationSubscribed":true,"userEmail":"roland.szucs@gmail.com","userName":"Roland","dateAdded":"17-02-21 11:11:19"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false},{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`InvoiceData`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-37268876,"type":"node","props":{"invoiceName":"Book and Walk Kft","taxNumber":"23345","dateAdded":"17-02-21","euTaxNumber":true}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false},{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`BnwAddress`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-930900166,"type":"node","props":{"country":"Hungary","zipCode":"1092","address":"Erkel utca 9.","city":"Budapest","dateAdded":"17-02-21"}},{"nodeRef":-1401737458,"type":"node","props":{"country":"Hungary","zipCode":"1092","address":"Ráday utca 9.","city":"Budapest","dateAdded":"17-02-21"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2017-02-21 12:11:19.098 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8 HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.296 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.d.h.response.AbstractHttpResponse  : Thread 1: Releasing HttpResponse
2017-02-21 12:11:19.298 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to create: nodeEntity -814245389:0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.298 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to create: nodeEntity -37268876:1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.298 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to create: nodeEntity -930900166:2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.298 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to create: nodeEntity -1401737458:3
2017-02-21 12:11:19.299 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, request url http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8
2017-02-21 12:11:19.300  INFO 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`HAS_INVOICEDATA`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":0,"relRef":-1219553025,"type":"rel","endNodeId":1}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false},{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`HAS_ADDRESS`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":1,"relRef":-1062181581,"type":"rel","endNodeId":2}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false},{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`HAS_DELIVERYINFO`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":0,"relRef":-1011104118,"type":"rel","endNodeId":2},{"startNodeId":0,"relRef":-62739928,"type":"rel","endNodeId":3}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
2017-02-21 12:11:19.300 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8 HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.445 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.d.h.response.AbstractHttpResponse  : Thread 1: Releasing HttpResponse
2017-02-21 12:11:19.445 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to (maybe) create: relEntity -1219553025:0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.446 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to (maybe) create: relEntity -1062181581:1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.446 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to (maybe) create: relEntity -1011104118:2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.446 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : to (maybe) create: relEntity -62739928:3
2017-02-21 12:11:19.446 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/8/commit HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.469 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, text: {"results":[],"errors":[]}
2017-02-21 12:11:19.469 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, Connection released
2017-02-21 12:11:19.469 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Commit transaction extent: 0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.470 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Committed
2017-02-21 12:11:19.470 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Close transaction extent: 0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.470 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Closing transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.470 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : creating new node id: -814245389, 0, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d
2017-02-21 12:11:19.472 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Removed object with id 0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.472 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Removed object with id Roland
2017-02-21 12:11:19.472 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Added object to node registry: 0, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d
2017-02-21 12:11:19.473 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Added object to node registry: Roland, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnWUser@3088660d
2017-02-21 12:11:19.473 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : creating new node id: -37268876, 1, hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c
2017-02-21 12:11:19.473 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Removed object with id 1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.473 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Added object to node registry: 1, hu.bookandwalk.domain.InvoiceData@238ad8c
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : creating new node id: -930900166, 2, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Removed object with id 2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Added object to node registry: 2, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@377c68c6
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor  : creating new node id: -1401737458, 3, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Removed object with id 3
2017-02-21 12:11:19.474 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.context.register.EntityRegister  : Added object to node registry: 3, hu.bookandwalk.domain.BnwAddress@538cd0f2
2017-02-21 12:11:19.479 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@74cf8b28] for Neo4j OGM transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.479 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.484 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, No current transaction, using auto-commit
2017-02-21 12:11:19.485 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver   : Thread: 1, request url http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
2017-02-21 12:11:19.488  INFO 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, url: http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) WHERE n.userName = { id } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p","parameters":{"id":"Roland"},"resultDataContents":["graph"],"includeStats":false}]}
2017-02-21 12:11:19.489 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 1, request: POST http://neo4j:RollerBlade1@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
2017-02-21 12:11:19.525 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.n.o.d.h.response.AbstractHttpResponse  : Thread 1: Releasing HttpResponse
2017-02-21 12:11:19.558 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2017-02-21 12:11:19.559 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] **o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Rolling back Neo4j transaction [null] on Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@74cf8b28]**
2017-02-21 12:11:19.560 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Close transaction extent: 0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.560 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Closing transaction
2017-02-21 12:11:19.560 DEBUG 5604 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction    : Thread 1: Rollback transaction extent: 0
2017-02-21 12:11:19.566  WARN 5604 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@3e57cd70] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void hu.bookandwalk.RepositoryTests.ShouldInsertUser()], instance [hu.bookandwalk.RepositoryTests@718607eb], exception [null]
```

The first log items show that a new session was created for the test transaction. What is strange the when the transaction started to be rolled back pring/neo4j saw the session but the transaction was null. Any idea what I am doing wrong. I have spent two days finding out the issue without success.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified Spring Integration tests will always rollback at the end of the test. That said, this does look like a bug. Please raise a ticket here and we will look into it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH

Comment: Is there any chance that this autorollback bug will be fixed? I raised a ticket in  jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH – digx1 but as the work log shows there was no any activity on this bug.

Comment: Can you try adding @EnableTransactionManagement to your configuration and see if that helps? We are a bit undermanned at the moment but we will get there.

Comment: @digx1 Thanks, I do not know how but now the integration test manages to make the rollback. I did not modify the test code at all it semms to me liek a red herring issue

Comment: No it is a bug as it should roll back without you needing to add that annotation. We have worked with the spring boot guys to fix this in both 1.5.3 and 2.0.0.